# Perl, making output go where it should

Tags: perl, foreach

It's a simple script that looks for files in spool/ and then processes them with a sister script. Then I want it to output the results of that into results/.

Here's the problem, with the code i've written the rusults go in results/spool/ and that's not right. How can i make them go in results/ only?

The $date_file i've been trying to use to make the output file contain the filename that it has processed. So im guessing there should be something to remove the /spool from that, but I can't get it sorted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use POSIX;
my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M.txt", localtime;

my @files = <spool/*.*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
    my $date_file = $file;
    system("$^X  wfreq.pl $file >> results/${date_file}_$date");
    unlink("$file");
}
```

Keep in mind Im real new at this...so be gentle :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you set

```
my $date_file = $file
```

and then you're writing to

```
results/${date_file}
```

If you try printing `$date_file`, you'll see that it is something like `spool/20121025_0000.txt`.  So when you concatonate it onto `results/`, you can see why they're ending up in `results/spool`

Easy fix is just to say

```
my $date_file = substr($file, 6);
```

to snip off the `spool/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using File::Basename's basename().

```
my $date_file = basename($file);
```

More info at http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html.